# Cartesian equation of a trapezium

Tags: geometry, relations

Is there a single (not piecewise or parametric) equation for a trapezium (trapezoid for our American members)?

EDIT: Since someone asked me to provide a more specific example for them, there is one for a square, which comes from defining a "unit circle" using the taxicab metric: $$|x| + |y| = 1$$ I was wondering not just if it's possible to generalise this to a trapezium, but what that equation would look like.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Can you make some examples to clarify what you are looking for? Is there a single equation of this kind for a square, say? Or for a triangle?

Comment: The absolute value is a parametric function. So the question is: what parametric functions are allowed?